# How do I get Visual Studio to recognize nested #include dependencies?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a file called 'source.cpp' in my Visual Studio project which #includes 'a.h' from a different project. 'a.h' in turn #includes more headers from that other project.

If changes are made to 'a.h' and I do a build of my project, VS tells me that it is up to date. It doesn't recognize that the changes to 'a.h' mean that my project must be rebuilt.

I can add 'a.h' to my project and that will fix the problem for changes made directly to 'a.h', but changes made to the headers that 'a.h' #includes will still not trigger a rebuild.

Is there a way to get VS to check the entire #include tree of a file when determining if the project is up to date?